# problems with media queries on my website

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I wrongly edited some code in css media queries a time ago and now on mobile devices the logo of my website look like this: [image]
.

The url of my page is: SplashYourCash.com

I cant get it to back to fill out the right space, maybe someone of you has an idea?

much greetings,
herrsocke

Comment: You are required to supply a minimal example of the code that causes the problem here. Links to your site won't help anyone in the future with the same question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: As pointed out, with the now accepted answer, the markup has changed on the linked web site, making this whole question and answer worthless to anyone else and needs to be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following `CSS` to your mobile `media-query`:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    margin-right: 0; 
}
```

It should fix it.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I put it in, but it didnt quite work yet. this is how i put it: 
@media all and (max-width: 380px) {
.navbar-toggle {margin-right: 0;} 
}

Comment: it is in line 299 in style.css

Comment: It is not appearing on your site!! It seems it is not published yet

Comment: sorry that was my fault! thanks alot for your help it it working now!

Comment: No problem :) but kindly mark it as the correct answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the bottom of your **style.css** file

```
@media all and (max-width: 380px) { 
        .logo {
            height: 62px;
        }
        .logo.logoshrink {
            height: 50px;
        }

        .navbar-toggle{
            margin-top:27px;
            margin-right:0;
        }
        .navbar-toggle.mt8{
            margin-top:8px;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks four your reply. i have putten it in, but it doesnt work yet. if you want to control its at line 301 in the style.css

Comment: @Herrsocke Are you using any types of caching? I don't see the code in the style.css file.

Comment: @Herrsocke, Make sure you are editing the correct css file. I still do not see the above code in the css file. [CSS file link](https://splashyourcash.com/templates/default/css/style.css)

Comment: oh sorry my fault! but i tried it and it worked! thank you very much. even its much better than before when it shrinks a little glitch is trigger now.

Comment: @Herrsocke, Great it helped you. :)